# Why's Clonezilla not able to complete the backup of my HDD (ext4)

Tags: backup, dvd, ext4, clonezilla

I have a single HDD with one single partition. What I need is to make an entire backup image of it and burn it to a DVD so that, in case of a messup, I can restore the entire HDD, as it was before.

What I already have is a bootable disc of clonezilla and a blank DVD. I've tried the defaults and failed at my task. So, help needed!

Comment: A DVD has 4,7 GB or 8,5 GB capacity. I don't think, that your partition is smaller, so it won't fix to a single DVD.

Comment: OK, I wasn't planning on that either, if only I could get an iso or other image file that i can break in to a couple of 4.7Gb's and burn them!